# Dynamically changed padding is not working with DIV with form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the padding of the DIV tag that is containing a form as it's child. Below is the HTML

```
 <div id="a">
   <form id="b" style="background-color:Red;height:300px">
      <input type="text" />
   </form>
 </div>​
```

And below is the CSS

```
 document.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('a').style.padding = "1% 1% 1% 1%"    
 };
```

Please check the behavior in ​[this](http://jsfiddle.net/74WbB/2/) fiddle. It is not working properly...

Comment: It seems to be adding the padding to the div, what exactly do you mean by properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather I think you're looking for something more like the forked fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/7QLAy/

The effect with the blue background is

http://jsfiddle.net/StkgZ/

Answer (score 2):

Rename the form id with something else and then try, both your form and div have the same name.

i have forked your fiddle jsfiddle.net/FAYvE

Comment: because you set background color for form you are not knowing that padding is changing.

Comment: OMG, I see the change again... I had applied 1% each.. But is not changed uniformly.. Please check again..